# Twitter BootStrap 2.3.2 Expand Collapse nested side bar menu items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Does Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 have something built in to do expand / hide nested side menus, or will It be better to do this using jquery (writing my own jquery)?

[image: Nested Items Closed]
[image: Nested Items Shown]

Comment: Were you able to accomplish it in 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't have any built in way to get similar behavior. I come across this implementation which doesn't require much custom code -

http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-plain-collapsible-tree-menu

It allows nested collapsable menu using bootstrap 2.3.x and jQuery snippet.

Comment: Sadly 3.0.1 removed `nav-list`